# How to Remove n-Tuples From List Where Each Element within the n-Tuples is Identical?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, duplicates, tuples

Let's say I have a list of n-tuples in Python, like so (using three-tuples in the example, but would want this to work for any tuple size):

```
myList = [('a','b','c'),
          ('a','a','a'),
          ('b','b','b'),
          ('d','e','f')
     ]
```

I want to remove any n-tuple where each element of the n-tuple is the same. In the example above, I would want to remove the tuples `('a','a','a')` and `('b','b','b')` because each of the elements in those tuples is the same.

I wrote a nested for loop that does this, but it seems really inefficient / not very Pythonic to do it this way. Any ideas on how to do this more simply and efficiently?

```
def tuple_removal(aList):
    elements = len(aList) # number of elements in the list
    tuple_size = len(aList[0]) # size of the tuple
    for i in reversed(range(elements)):
        same_element_count = 1 # initialize counter to 1
        for j in range(tuple_size-1):
            # add one to counter if the jth element is equal to the j+1 element
            same_element_count += aList[i][j] == aList[i][j+1]
        if same_element_count == tuple_size:
            # remove the tuple at the ith index if the count of elements that are the same
            # is equal to the size of the tuple
            del aList[i]
    return(aList)

myNewList = tuple_removal(myList)
myNewList

# Output
myNewList = [('a','b','c'),
          ('d','e','f')
     ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a *list comprehension* and check that the count of the first element in each matching tuple is not the same as the length of the tuple:

```
>>> r = [i for i in myList if i.count(i[0]) != len(i)]
>>> r
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```

Comment: I've tested all the answers here and I believe yours is the fastest ;-) +1

Comment: Thanks! I'll take @leaf 's word for it on speed. 13 lines of code reduced to 1. This is great. (And thanks for all of the other answers too).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [*list comprehension*](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) and test to see if all elements in a given tuple are equal using the builtin [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function.

```
>>> myList = [('a','b','c'),
          ('a','a','a'),
          ('b','b','b'),
          ('d','e','f')
     ]
>>> 
>>> [el for el in myList if not all(x == el[0] for x in el)]
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert each tuple to a set; if the result has length 1, all elements were the same. Use this in a list comprehension as a filter, keeping all tuples which have more than one unique element:

```
def tuple_removal(lst):
    return [t for t in lst if len(set(t)) > 1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> myList = [('a','b','c'),
...           ('a','a','a'),
...           ('b','b','b'),
...           ('d','e','f')
...      ]
>>> tuple_removal(myList)
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f')]
```